# Fixed menu position top on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

Menu is fixed and and offset from top height of header.
but when I scroll header goes up because it's not fixed. So menu should also go up on scroll.

find demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/g6wfy740/1/)

I just want there should be no offset margin from top on menu when scroll down.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var y = $(window).scrollTop();
  var bgp = $(window).scrollTop();
  var mtv = $('.menu').position().top;
  if(y > 0){
    $('.menu').css({'top': + mtv-bgp +'px'});  
  } else{
    $('.menu').css({'top': + bgp-mtv+'px'}); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i get what you want correct then this should help you:

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.header{
    background:#ddd;
    height:80px;
    position:relative;
}
.container{
    height:1000px;
    background:#eee;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
.menu{
    background:#000;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    top:80px;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:11;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
#toggle{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:yellow;
    float:left;
    margin:10px 20px;
}
```

and the js

```
   $(window).scroll(function(){
      var y = $('body').scrollTop();
      if(y > 80){
        $('.menu').css({'top':'0px'});  
      } 
        else if(y<80)
            $('.menu').css({'top':'80px'}); 
    });
```

i also updated your fiddel :
https://jsfiddle.net/g6wfy740/2/

Comment: But I was like [http://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/fLz34vt4/](http://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/fLz34vt4/)..
see the background-position is change on the amount of scroll by scrollbar. I was same like this.

Comment: can you explain more i didn't get the idea? are you trying to perform parallax scroll? if so you may want to look at this quotation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657199/parallax-scrolling

Comment: What is I wanted that's almost done. But the only problem is header is moving up with scroll but it's not stopping when it reaches it's top position. [https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/g6wfy740/4/](https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/g6wfy740/4/). menu should not go minus value it's top position.

Comment: if you want the menu to stop when it reach the top you should check if the result less than 0 if so reset it to zero  var result =  headerHeight-bgp;
        if(result<0){result=0;}. like this  https://jsfiddle.net/g6wfy740/12/