# Relationship Between 2 Divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

Imagine div1 and div2. div1 has 100% width and is 800px high. div2 is fixed to top of browser, also has 100% width and is maybe 3000px high. I am trying to land so you see div1 but, when you scroll down, div1 slides up out of the way, revealing div2 and all it's content. It seems easy but, I can't figure it out.

```css
div1 {
  width:100%;
  height: 800px;
  position: ???;
  z-index:100;
  background-color: white;
}


div2 {
    width:100%
    height: 3000px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Seems like if you just unfixed div1? Isn't what you described just a standard scroll? Other things become visible as you scroll?

Comment: agreed but, it isn't working : /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, your sample code has some flaws such as wrong CSS selectors (unless you created custom tags named "div1" etc.), a missing ending `;` in div2 CSS rule (`width:100%`). You also need to position your fixed div at left/top 0 to position it behind the moving div.

To make your moving div move, add a `bottom margin` the size as its `height` and it will scroll out of sight/viewport.

This technique is sometimes called ***parallax scrolling*** and [here is a post showing more how/what one can do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657199/parallax-scrolling)

```css
.div1 {
  width:100%;
  height: 800px;
  position: relative;
  z-index:100;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 800px;
}


.div2 {
 top: 0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 height: 3000px;
 position: fixed;
 background-color: black;
 }
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

Comment: Perhaps point out that the selectors are missing `.`?

Comment: @ParkSoonWai Will do that and explain when knowing what OP looked for, as it was not only that.